# Posting data from javascript to asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Not sure if there is a simple method or if it will require brute force but I am currently developing a page that contains the [JQVMap plugin](https://jqvmap.com/). I am trying to make the "onRegionClick" function post the country "region" to the next page called country.asp but have not been successful thus far.

Below I have included how the script for the plugin currently operates to display an alert containing country name and region code.

```
<script>
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
      map: 'world_en',
      backgroundColor: null,
      color: '#ffffff',
      hoverOpacity: 0.7,
      selectedColor: 'gold',
      enableZoom: true,
      showTooltip: true,
      values: sample_data,
      scaleColors: ['#111111', '#111111'],
      onRegionClick: function (event, code, region) {
        {
          var message = 'You clicked "'
                + region 
                + '" which has the code: '
                + code.toUpperCase();

           alert(message);
        }
        window.location.replace("country.asp");
      }
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What does "post the country "region" to the next" mean? To the next what? Page, I guess? Does it need to be a POST, or will it work as GET? If it will work as a GET you can just put the variable on the querystring, like `window.location.replace("country.asp?region=" + encodeURIComponent(region));`. If POST is required, you'll have to fake a form submit.

Comment: Do u get any error? R u sure about the structure of sample_data?

Comment: I will try ADyson's suggest method as soon as possible, thank you